# i want to execute js file for adding styles to html but can't load js file in typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript

I am learning angular 2. and i want to add script tags inside the templateUrl.
or i want to run the script file inside the typescript file.
i have home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-index',
  templateUrl : 'app/home.html',
  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ]


})
export class IndexComponent {
  abt = 'HOME';
}
```

and home.html file contains

```
<div class="main-container">
  <header class="page-header">
    <div class="background-image-holder"> <img class="background-image" alt="Background Image" src="img/tab/home_slide_bk_1.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <h1 class="text-white space-bottom-medium">A complete guaranteed and programmatic platform</h1>
          <a [routerLink]="['/contact']" class="btn btn-primary btn-filled">Learn more</a> </div>
      </div>
```

i want to add my JS file inside this html file but TypeScript removes script tags so i cant able to make changes to home.html file

my JS file is scriptshome.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    "use strict";
    $('.background-image-holder').each(function(){
        var imgSrc= $(this).children('img').attr('src');
        $(this).css('background', 'url("' + imgSrc + '")');
        $(this).children('img').hide();
        $(this).css('background-position', '50% 0%');
    });
```

the JS file contains multiple functions like above mentioned
i want to use those all functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the functions inside your component and call them from the constructor.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-index',
  templateUrl : 'app/home.html',
  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ]
})

export class IndexComponent {
  public abt = 'HOME';

constructor() {
   changeImg();
}

 changeImg() {
  $('.background-image-holder').each(function(){
        var imgSrc= $(this).children('img').attr('src');
        $(this).css('background', 'url("' + imgSrc + '")');
        $(this).children('img').hide();
        $(this).css('background-position', '50% 0%');
    });
  }
}
```

If you want to call the function after DOM load, then you can call it within `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-index',
  templateUrl : 'app/home.html',
  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ]
})

export class IndexComponent {
  public abt = 'HOME';

ngAfterViewInit() {
   changeImg();
}

 changeImg() {
  $('.background-image-holder').each(function() {
        var imgSrc= $(this).children('img').attr('src');
        $(this).css('background', 'url("' + imgSrc + '")');
        $(this).children('img').hide();
        $(this).css('background-position', '50% 0%');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to execute complete js file . and it cant understand the $ sign

Comment: You have to add a reference to jQuery in your html file, or in your main Component.